# How to used Material Design Transition when fragment changed in Android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-transitions

I like new [Transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions) introduced with [Android material design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) like that :

[image]

But, I want used it when I replaced fragment after selected an item in my Drawer :

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

Is that possible? Used the same logic with `EnterTransition` / `ExitTransition` and `Explode` transition animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These transitions are for **activities**, not for **fragments**, See [below from documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions) these are specified for **windowExitTransition** & **windowEnterTransition**

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
  <!-- enable window content transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>

  <!-- specify enter and exit transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/explode</item>
  <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/explode</item>

  <!-- specify shared element transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
  <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
</style>
```

You can try to achieve same for fragments as well specifying transitions in your  **fragmenttransanction**.

Comment: Thank you, but I know how the transitions do for activities. But, can you show me an example with fragmenttransanction?

Comment: it looks like this fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left)